# Android, What is the quickest and most efficient method of converting a postcode to longitude and latitude in Java?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know how to get a postcode from longitude and latitude coordinates but I don't know how to get the reverse (longitude and latitude from a postcode) How do I do this?

In **Android**

Code for getting a postcode from longitude and latitude coordinates:

```
Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> address = null;

if (geoCoder != null){
   try {
       address= geoCoder.getFromLocation(latPoint, lngPoint, 1);
       } catch (IOException e1) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e1.printStackTrace();
      }
      if (address.size()> 0){
        String postCode = address.get(0).getPostalCode();
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've pretty much answered your own question. The Android Geocoder class can be used to do both geocoding and reverse geocoding. Address-to-latlon conversion is referred to as geocoding; latlon-to-address conversion (as in your example) is referred to as reverse geocoding.  I've modified your example to show a geocoding example using a UK post code:

```
    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> address = null;

    if (geoCoder != null) {
        try {
            address = geoCoder.getFromLocationName("KT48LY", 10);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (address.size() > 0) {
            Address first = address.get(0);
            double lat = first.getLatitude();
            double lon = first.getLongitude();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Geocoder is just a facade. The implementation is device-dependent and not mandatory. If Google's own Geocoder service is the backend, the [getFromLocationName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocationName%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method may work reliably enough, while specifying as a query string a combination of ZIP code and country such as:

```
10007, USA
```

If that does not work for you reliably you can use the geo location database from [GeoNames.org](http://www.geonames.org/). I just tried a query based on a ZIP code and country name and received the correct result from them.

GeoNames has a web service API with support for JSON and XML data and they also provide download links for various client libraries for different programming languages.